# SQL - sorting table with parent child relation

Tags: sql, sorting

We have a table with a parent-child relation and would like to get it sorted. The sorting criteria is so that when iterating though the result the row matching a parent ID should already be there :

```
ID   PARENT_ID 
EF01 EF02         // This is wrong as the row EF02 is after and will fail.
EF02    
BB   AA           // here BB < AA
AA   EF01
```

The problem is that both key are string, therefore sorting by ID or PARENT_ID is not going to fix the problem.

Comment: What DBMS do you use? SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL ...?

Comment: Why will an `ORDER BY PARENT_ID ASC,ID ASC` fail when both columns are strings?

Comment: Rabudde, due to the nature of the ID - I'll change the example so it's easier to see. Mikael, is there no a generic solution, if no it's Oracle

Comment: Do the parent records have a NULL or empty string in the parent_id field?

Comment: Let's say null if it's the root

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Oracle, using [hierarchical queries](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/connect_by.html):

```
 select id, parent_id, level from the_table
 start with parent_id is null
 connect by prior id = parent_id;
```

Comment: Do you know the solution for SQL Server ?

Comment: No, but @Mikael seems to have one in his answer.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have Oracle to test on. This works in SQL Server and I believe it should work in Oracle as well.

```
with R(id, parent_id, lvl) as
(
  select id,
         parent_id,
         1
  from YourTable
  where parent_id is null
  union all
  select T.id,
         T.parent_id,
         R.lvl + 1
  from YourTable as T
    inner join R
      on T.parent_id = R.id
)
select R.id,
       R.parent_id
from R
order by lvl
```

There might be other ways to do the same in Oracle.

Comment: Thanks, that's cool about stackoverflow I learn everytime I ask something :-)

Comment: This query also runs on PostgreSql. Just add RECURSIVE keyword after with. (i.e. with **RECURSIVE** R(id, parent_id, lvl) as)

Answer (score 0):

Any DBMS will NOT guarantee the order the rows are delivered in unless you ask for for the data in a specific order using the "ORDER BY CLAUSE".

In most DBMSes you can specify the data is stored in a particular order using a "CLUSTERING INDEX" on the column you want to order by. However you wont necessarily get the data back in this order unless you specify an "ORDER BY" in your SQL. Furthermore in many DBMSes this is a "best effort" specification for internal reasons (disk space, concurrent units of work etc.) it may not be possible for the DBMS to store the data in the requested order.