# Sort Data based on uniqueidentifier data type column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have table in that there are relation between Parent and Child, in this my ParentID and SID data type is  **uniqueidentifier**, now I want to sort the data based on the it's ParentID. the value in my table is like below:

[image]

How can I sort the data of this table based on the ParentID.
Any one please help me to archive this.

Comment: You can use a recursive CTE to build a `level` column and sort by that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117722/sql-sorting-table-with-parent-child-relation/7117868#7117868

Comment: @Mikael: thanks.. It is the exact what I want.. this solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use an `ORDER BY` in your `SELECT` statement.

```
SELECT SubjectName, ParentID, SubjectID, SID
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY ParentID
```

It might look like the data isn't sorted but it is, it just sorts different since it is a uniqueidentifier.  Here is some info I found on sorting by GUIDs.

[How are GUIDs sorted on SQL server?](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alberto_ferrari/archive/2007/08/31/how-are-guids-sorted-by-sql-server.aspx)