# icCube parent/child dimension sort error

Tags: iccube

I have a child/parent hierarchy with columns: AreaName,ParentArea
When I build the cube, I get the error:

The data of the parent/child hierarchy (AreaName) must be sorted (child-id:X,parent-id:Y).

This error is referring to the 2nd row in my csv data source. The first row has a blank value for ParentArea so maybe this is having some impact?

I double checked my source data and the values are sorted by AreaName,ParentArea. I then changed the sort order to ParentArea,AreaName and that seems to work although I don't understand why.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In icCube you've a view that allows for sorting a parent / child relation as expected by the dimension ([doc](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/schemas_cubes/etl_sort.php)).

If your data source is a relational database the algorithm for sorting a parent/child relation are described in this stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117722/sql-sorting-table-with-parent-child-relation).